# What is wing inductance?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing, drag

I am currently trying to understand the ground roll and climbing stage of normal aircraft.
I came across this formula which is an expression of the airplanes drag:

$X_a = c_{{x}_a} S \frac{\rho V^2}{2}$

where: $ c_{{x}_a} = c_{x0} + A c^2_{x_{a}}$

- S: wing area
- $\rho$: air density
- V: velocity
- $c_{x0}$: drag coefficient when the lifting force = 0
- $c_{x}$: drag coefficient

A is said to be the wing inductance. Could somebody explain what is meant by wing inductance?

Comment: Are there typos in your formulae?  Should the second one not be $c_{x_a}=c_{x_0}+A c_{z_a}^2$ where $c_{z_a}$ is the lift coefficient?

Comment: @Christo nope, no mistakes this is the formula that I was provided. Unless there is a mistake in the docs I was given...

Answer (score 5):

$$A = \frac{1}{\pi \cdot e \cdot AR}$$
where
$\pi = 3.14159....$, $e$ is the [Oswald efficiency factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oswald_efficiency_number), and $AR$ is aspect ratio of the wing.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained the physical significance of this number.

Comment: It would indeed be nice if you could explain the physical significance of this number.

Answer (score 1):

The drag of a conventional aircraft is
$$
D = \frac{1}{2}\rho V^2 S C_D
$$
where
$\rho$ is the air density,
$V$ is the true airspeed,
$S$ is the wing reference area, and
$C_D$ is the drag coefficient.

The drag coeffcient can be approximated by
$$
C_D = C_{D_0} + \frac{C_L^2}{\pi eA\!R}
$$
where
$C_{D_0}$ is the zero-lift drag coefficient,
$C_L$ is the lift coefficient,
$\pi=3.1416\ldots$, 
$e$ is the span efficiency factor (also called Oswald's efficiency factor), and
$A\!R$ is the aspect ratio of the wing.
The term
$$
\frac{C_L^2}{\pi eA\!R}
$$
is called the *induced drag coefficient*.

I suspect that there is a typo in the document where you obtained your formulae.
The second formula should be $c_{x_a} = c_{x_o}+Ac_{z_a}^2$ corresponding to $C_D = C_{D_0} + C_L^2/(\pi e A\!R)$.
In that case, the $A$ in your second formula corresponds to $1/(\pi e A\!R)$ as @Jared pointed out.
The term "wing inductance" that your source uses is probably some variation of the term "induced drag" due to the wing.

You can read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift-induced_drag) to find out more about "induced drag", also called "lift-induced drag".